# Pandas - count things of one column by a condition of other

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame `d` of games played of the game Go. The important columns for these are the player name, and if they won or not that particular game. How can I make a new DataFrame with a column that is Player name (without repeating names), the total games they played and the total number they won. Example:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'Nombres': ['pepe','tito','pepe','pepe'], 'col2': ['Win','Lost','Win','Lost']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

This is what I currently do, counting the number of games played per user:

```
df3 = df2.groupby(['Jugador']).size().reset_index(name='count')
```

How can I add the column of how many games each player won?

Comment: Do you mean `df2.Nombres.value_counts()`

Comment: This would be called *"aggregate Wins by Player"* or *"tabulate Wins and Matches by Player"*. Also, you could name 'col2' ('Win'/'Lost' column) 'Result'.

Answer (score 3):

Few ways (feel free to add more)

## 1

```
df2.groupby(['Nombres','col2'])['col2'].count().to_frame()
              col2
Nombres col2      
pepe    Lost     1
        Win      2
tito    Lost     1
```

## 2

```
pd.crosstab(df2.Nombres,df2.col2,df2.col2,aggfunc='count').fillna(0)
col2     Lost  Win
Nombres           
pepe      1.0  2.0
tito      1.0  0.0
```

## 3

```
df2.loc[df2['col2'] == 'Win']['Nombres'].value_counts()
pepe    2
Name: Nombres, dtype: int64
```

## 4

```
df2.loc[df2['col2'] == 'Win'].groupby('Nombres').size()
Nombres
pepe    2
dtype: int64
```

## 5

```
df2['win_counter'] = df2.groupby('Nombres')['col2'].apply(lambda x : x.eq('Win').cumsum())
print(df2)
     Nombres  col2    win_counter
0    pepe     Win              1
1    tito     Lost             0
2    pepe     Win              2
3    pepe     Lost             2
```

Comment: @ansev i hardly use pivot i most go for `pd.crosstab` but feel free to add :)

Comment: pandas crosstab uses pivot table internally, and if you check it sometimes it can be slow

Comment: @ansev that makes total sense, thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2):

#### IIUC, [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html)

```
new_df = (df2.pivot_table(index = 'Nombres',columns = 'col2',
                          values = 'col2',
                          aggfunc = 'size',
                          fill_value = 0)
            #.loc[:,['Win']] #if you want drop the column of Lost
             .assign(Total_Match=lambda x: x.sum(axis=1))
             .rename_axis(columns = None)
             .reset_index())
print(new_df)
```

**Output**

```
  Nombres  Lost  Win  Total_Match
0    pepe     1    2            3
1    tito     1    0            1
```